# How to install VNC on ARCH Linux arm LAMP server (PogoPlug)?

Tags: linux, lamp, vnc

I saw a [PogoPlug](http://pogoplug.com/) in the store and thought, "I could probably make a tiny server out of that!"  I am coding a website for a friend and having a simple little server to test my PHP would be awesome and wouldn't require me to run something like XAMPP on my local machine.  So, I bought the machine and used the tutorial found [on lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5637092/turn-a-pogoplug-into-a-fully-featured-linux-web-server/all).  My PogoPlug LAMP server is working perfectly but now I'm having a usability issue.  I can SSH into the server to pass files from Windows 7 to the Linux Server but I have to edit the file, save, SSH the files to the server, and then test.  I'd much prefer to alter the files directly on the server, save, and then test--cutting out the SSH aspect.  I found that there may be a way in which that can be done with VNC but I have not idea what that is or how to set it up or even if it would work on this setup.  This is my question:

What is VNC exactly?  Will it allow me to use Windows Explorer to access the files on the server?  How can I set it up?  AND do you know if it will work on the PogoPlug LAMP?

I know these are multiple questions but the setup aspect is really what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking SSH is a file transfer protocol.  Although you can do that with SSH, there is much more to it.  You can open up a terminal using SSH, directly on the server.  In Windows, you can use Putty or Cygwin.  Once logged onto the server, you can use a pre-installed terminal based editor or you can install one.  For example, vi is a great but not very intuitive editor that folks use.  Once the files are edited, you will not need to transfer them to the server.

Check out for more information:

http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Windows

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This doesn't really answer their question and might be better posed as comments on the original question.  It is a pretty question.